# Find ISBN with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

If have a text (actually lots of texts), where somewhere is one ISBN inside, and I have to find it.

I know: my ISBN-13 will start with "978" followed by 10 digits.

I don't kow: how many '-' (minus) there are and if they are at the correct place.

My code will only find me the ISBN without any Minus:

```
regex=r'978[0-9]{10}'
pattern = re.compile(regex, re.UNICODE)
for match in pattern.findall(mytext):
    print(match)
```

But how can I find ISBN like these:

- 978-123-456-789-0
- 978-1234-567890
- 9781234567890
- etc...

Is this possible with one regex-pattern?

Thanks!

Comment: How are ISBNs separated from the rest of the text? [May there be `-` before/after an ISBN?](http://ideone.com/HVRHxz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matches 10 digits and allows one optional hyphen before each:

```
regex = r'978(?:-?\d){10}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't have 2 consecutive hyphens, and it must end with a digit:

`r'978(-?\d){10}'`

... allowing for a hyphen right after then `978`, mandating a digit after every hyphen (does not end in a hyphen), and allowing for consecutive digits by making each hyphen optional.

I would add `\b` before the `978` and after then `{10}`, to make sure the ISBN's are well separated from surrounding text.

Also, I would add `?:` right after the opening parenthesis, to make those non-capturing (slightly better performance, and also more expressive), making it:

`r'\b978(?:-?\d){10}\b'`

Answer (score 1):

What about adding the `-` char in the pattern for the regex? This way, it will look for any combination of (number or `-`)x10 times.

```
regex=r'978[0-9\-]{10}'
```

Although it may be better to use

```
regex=r'978[0-9\-]+'
```

because otherwise if we use `{10}` and some `-` are found, not all the digits will be found.

#### Test

```
>>> import re
>>> regex=r'978[0-9\-]+'
>>> pattern = re.compile(regex, re.UNICODE)
>>> mytext="978-123-456-789-0"
>>> for match in pattern.findall(mytext):
...     print(match)
... 
978-123-456-789-0
>>> mytext="978-1234-567890"
>>> for match in pattern.findall(mytext):
...     print(match)
... 
978-1234-567890
>>> mytext="9781234567890"
>>> for match in pattern.findall(mytext):
...     print(match)
... 
9781234567890
>>>
```

Comment: Your pattern and demo do not match. Your suggested pattern would **not** allow the demonstrated matches.

Comment: Ops, solved @MartijnPieters. It **is** matching the examples given by the OP.

Comment: It matches the examples only partially.

Comment: @JanneKarila oh now I see: there should be 10 digits + an undetermined amount of `-`. Mine just matches the first 10 characters : (

Answer (score 1):

You can try to match every digits and `-` characters. In that case you can't know how many characters find however:

```
regex=r'978[\d\-]+\d'
pattern = re.compile(regex, re.UNICODE)
for match in pattern.findall(mytext):
    print(match)
```

If your ISBN is stucked between other digits or hyphens, you'll have some problems, but if it's clearly seperated, no worries :)

**EDIT**: According to the first comment, you can add an extra \d at the end of the regex (I've updated my code just below) because you know that an ISBN ends with a digit.

Comment: It'll have to end in a digit, though, so add a final `\d`, and he has clearly indicated 13 digits total, so add a quantifier, at least a range.

Comment: You don't know the number of hyphens (or you choose a maximum value like 6 hyphens max and then you put a `{10,16}`)

Comment: Exactly. That's what I meant when I wrote "range".

Comment: Actually your latest edit: (1) allows for ending with a hyphen (2) allows 16 digits

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way should be

```
regex=r'978[-0-9]{10,15}'
```

which will accept them.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking : [ISBN Detail and Contraints](https://www.isbn-international.org/content/what-isbn)

Easy one `regex = r'^(978-?|979-?)?\d(-?\d){9}$'`

Strong one `isbnRegex = r'^(978-?|979-?)?\d{1,5}-?\d{1,7}-?\d{1,6}-?\d{1,3}$'` and include length check of 10 and 13 after removing hypen (Note : Also add substring check for length = 13 ie. only for 978 or 979, Some edge case still need to be checked)